# How can i get access token by using Client Id and client secret

Tags: javascript, html, json, foursquare

I have practiced getting for access token by using Temboo on authorization Url and callback id. But after using this callback id get error like "A Server Error has occurred: The specified object doesn't exist or you don't have the necessary permissions to access it. The error occurred in the Expression (Get callback data) step.". I am not getting how approach this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Please show some code. As it is, it's extremely hard to help you

Comment: Hi Avey, I will be share my code but first of all i need to get " access token " through temboo or any other way. Do you have any idea how to get " access token " please share with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I work for Temboo.

The best place to start with Foursquare OAuth is by watching the short screencast below that explains everything you need to know about how Temboo simplifies OAuth. The video discusses working with the Fitbit API, but once you know how that one works you'll be able to use the Foursquare API in exactly the same manner.

http://www.temboo.com/videos#oauthchoreos

Setup instructions for the Foursquare OAuth Choreos can also be found here:

https://temboo.com/library/Library/Foursquare/OAuth/

Hopefully this helps, but feel free to contact us via email (support AT temboo.com) if you have further questions - we're always happy to help.

Comment: Thank you kbuck, Yes I was practiced same as like that, as in that video you shared. But i get this error after submitting the callback id "A Server Error has occurred: The specified object doesn't exist or you don't have the necessary permissions to access it. The error occurred in the Expression (Get callback data) step."

Comment: Might be is there any other mistake like it mentioned " permissions to access ". And i am practiced only on java script.

Comment: I am using foursquare api for my web site. so where i get document for web applications. Why because in this document https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth.html#access they given only for iOS and Android.

Comment: Hi. One of you problems may be that you aren't running the FinalizeOauth Choreo before the callbackID expires. The callbackID will normally expire after 10 minutes, so if you waited more than 10 minutes between running InitializeOauth and FinalizeOauth, you will receive that error. If you have any other questions, feel free to contact us at https://www.temboo.com/support.

Comment: Hi. Yes I tried now I get this error " A Step Error has occurred: "The Choreo was not able to retrieve the authorization callback data within the specified timeout. Verify that the user has clicked "allow" at the authorization URL returned by the InitializeOAuth Choreo.". The error occurred in the Stop (Callback error) step.

Comment: " callback error " which means i am using " sudhakarsanjeevi/29b52f3b-a321-4a96-8707-2efcce16cd42 " like this with. Is anything wrong by using   my name ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused using the callback url. Suppose 3 users are signing in at the same time. The callback url is working, but I don't see any parameters. Do you need to check each callback id to see which user has clicked allow?

Comment: Ah, so I should store the callback id and token secret in the session and verify it when running FinalizeOAuth ?

Comment: @Guus Please contact us at https://temboo.com/support and we'll be happy to help with your issue.

Comment: @kbuck3 thx, I got the initialize and finalize steps working. If storing the callbackid/token in the session is not the proper way please let me know then I will contact support.